# How to retrieve collection of parent records conditional on properties of child in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have created models with controllers for a Project class, and defined a onetoMany relationship with a child class Invoice, as well as a belongsTo on the Invoice to enforce the relationship between them. I'm wanting to retrieve a collection of all Projects created within a date range (using whereBetween) in which their related Invoices have a notNull value in a specific column.

Here's what I've got in the Project

```
/**
 * Project has many Invoices.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function invoices()
{
    // hasMany(RelatedModel, foreignKeyOnRelatedModel = project_id, localKey = id)
    return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class);
}
```

And then here's the Invoice relationship

```
public function project()
{
    // belongsTo(RelatedModel, foreignKey = project_id, keyOnRelatedModel = id)
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}
```

And then on one of my Controllers, where I'm trying to retrieve them

```
//Attempt at getting projects
    $projects = \App\Project::whereBetween('created_at', [$dateFromFilter, $dateToFilter])->whereHas('invoices', function($inv){
        $inv->whereNotNull('approvedDate');
    })->get();
```

I really appreciate any support as I've been racking my brain on this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found a solution. Thought I'd post it in case someone else was looking for something similar.

```
$projects = \App\Project::where('company_id', auth()->user()->company_id)->whereBetween('created_at', [$dateFromFilter, $dateToFilter])->whereHas('invoices', function($query){
        $query->whereNotNull('approvedDate');
    })->get();
```

I think part of my struggle was I was getting errors on 'whereHas' not being a recognized method, but that's because I was calling it on a Collection I had already defined earlier in my code, rather than as part of a new query builder.